# En MySQL como se deben declarar los tipos de datos en caso de usar los siguiente elementos en JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

1)Si se va a crear una contraseña con JPasswordField que tipo de dato se debe declarar en la base de datos SQL ... seria varchar o que otro? tengo entendido que para las contraseñas se encriptan y piden otro tipo de dato.

2) En caso de JComboBox que tipo de dato se recibiría en la base de datos?

3) En caso de RadioButtom o CheckBox ??

4) En caso de tener un espacio para guardar al foto de un usuario como se crearía? creo que hay dos maneras no? el de agregar la imagen como tal un binario o algo asi.. y la otra que seria solo agregar la ruta en ese caso el dato seria de tipo varchar o text? aveces las rutas pueden ser largas.. D:

5) Fechas desde Java con [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar) a mysql date se puede? como?

Gracias por su ayuda estoy empezando estoy haciendo un proyecto con Java en NetBeans y con phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

1. La contraseña puedes insertarla como texto cogiendo el valor del campo del `JPasswordField`, por lo que puedes usar **`varchar`**. Por motivos de *seguridad* podrías encriptar primero la contraseña antes de insertarla en la Base de datos. Para ello puedes usar por ejemplo ***MD5***, aunque posiblemente no sea el más seguro de todos (pero es una forma).

---

2. Para el `JComboBox` puedes usar varios tipos dependiendo realmente del valor que guarde tu Combo. (Sabemos que los ComboBox pueden guardar varios tipos tales como `Integer`, `String`, ...)

---

3. En caso de `RadioButton` o `CheckBox` puedes usar **`tinyint(1)`**. El valor `0` es considerado `false`, y el valor `1` es considerado `true`.

---

4. Para guardar una foto te recomiendo guardar la foto en el host, e insertar la ruta en la base de datos. Para ello dependiendo del tamaño de las rutas de tus imágenes, vas a usar **`varchar`** o **`text`** (Debería llegarte con **`varchar`** por su límite de hasta *8000 carácteres*).

---

5. Las fechas en MySQL se controlan con **`datetime`**.

Comment: MD5 nunca debe utilizarse para cifrado de contraseñas. No es que no sea de los más seguros es que es inseguro de por sí. De todas formas, atendiendo a la pregunta, el campo de la base de datos puede ser Varchar ya que aunque se vaya a cifrar la contraseña el valor resultante será una cadena de texto, la longitud de la misma dependería del método de cifrado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando cojas el value del campo de la contraseña pásalo a String y así te aseguras de que metes una cadena.

Del combo box vas a usar el value y por tanto será una cadena, lo mismo en caso de radiobutton y checkbox.

La foto yo la guardaría como una cadena que sea la ruta de la imagen.

Y en cuanto a las fechas no sabría decirte como funcionan porque no he utilizado JCalendar